# Why does the page number slightly move its position to the bottom line when a listing code is written on two pages?

Tags: listings, texstudio, code

I noticed that whenever I add a source code to my latex file, the numbers of the page where the code is added look displaced. I do not know if there is a reason in the listing configuration that causes this, but this is an example compilable code with all the Packages I used and also the picture of the page number that slightly moved its position to the line it should stay below the line.
[image]

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,a4paper,oneside,listof=totoc,plainfootsepline]{scrbook}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} 
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{subsubsection}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,head=33pt,foot=18pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\def\quad{\hskip1em\relax}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{microtype}

\RequirePackage{scrlfile}
\ReplacePackage{scrpage2}{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{subcaption}  
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
%\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\usepackage{babel,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X} % suppress full justification
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx} % for \qty macro; use commas as decimal markers
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} 
\setitemize{leftmargin=*,noitemsep}
\setenumerate{leftmargin=*,noitemsep} 
\newlist{Schritte}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[Schritte, 1]{label = Schritt \arabic*:}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{{\textit{#1}\hfill}}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\captionsetup{justification=centering}

\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage[headsepline,footsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\automark[section]{chapter}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand*\MakeUppercase[1]{#1}

\ihead{}
\chead{}
\ohead{\rightmark}

\ifoot{}
\cfoot[\thepage]{\thepage}
\ofoot{}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

\newcommand*{\formelentry}[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{for}{formel}{\protect\numberline{\theequation} #1}}%

\usepackage{bigstrut}
\setlength\bigstrutjot{3pt} 

\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{.1\baselineskip}}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}


\usepackage{courier}

\lstdefinestyle{customc}{
    breaklines=true,
    language=C,
    showstringspaces=false,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{blue},
    commentstyle={\color{green!40!black}},
    identifierstyle=\color{black},
}

\lstset{escapechar=@,style=customc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\BeraMonottfamily{%
    \def\fvm@Scale{0.6}% scales the font down
    \fontfamily{fvm}\selectfont% selects the Bera Mono font
}
\makeatother

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\BeraMonottfamily,lineskip={-6pt}, 
}
\begin{document}
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT . TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT . TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT\\
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT . TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT\\
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT . TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT\\
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT . TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT\\
\begin{lstlisting}
    #define ENDCOMMAND             ":END"
    #define COM1                   "START:DO_THE_COMMAND" //
    #define COM2                   "START:GET_COM2" //
    #define COM3                   "START:GET_COM3_" //Anmeldung
    #define COM4                   "START:WRITE_" //
    #define COM5                   "START:READ_" //
    #define COM6                   "START:READ_MULTI_"//
    #define COM7                   "START:SET_PRO_PAGE_" //
    #define COM8                   "START:SET_PRO_PAGES_"//
    #define COM9                   "START:PW_INPUT_"//
   \end{lstlisting}
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT . TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXb TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT\\
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT . TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT\\
TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT . TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT\\
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for the help in advance!

Comment: A good place to start is to make your example as simple as possbile. Yes, that is a process, but often you will find the actual problem this way. For example I switched to `book` and removed the koma and header stuff and used the standard `plain` page style. Then there is no issue.

Comment: @daleif, I just added all packages I used and removed some and posted it, because I did not know if there are some packages that caused the problem. Can you tell me what line you changed please? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: That negative lineskip on the listings settings seems sus as well

Comment: Basically, outcomment a package, see if the doc still compiles and the result is the same, then that package is probably not relevant to the issue. Repeat

Comment: Going back to your original example, that `lineskip={-6pt}` is the problem, one should never do something like that. What exacty is the goal with that setting?

Comment: You are right @dailef. Thank you so much. I will just make -6 to 0. You can write it as an answer instead of an comment and I will accept it. Thanks for solving the error.

Comment: @daleif I know why there is -6 points there. This is because the code tend to take too much place and it turns out this lineksip makes in fit in one page.

Comment: you should really avoid loading so many packages it seems unlikely you use them all, and several are listed more than once tabularx 3 times, tabuarray twice  siunitx three times ....  it makes it harder for you or people trying to help you debug the document. Only ever load packages you use in the document and only specify them once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the negative lineskip in

```
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\BeraMonottfamily,lineskip={-6pt}, 
}
```

If you just want `lstlisting` to be singlespaced, you can use

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\singlespacing}
```

If you're using the latest LaTeX kernel you can replace `etoolbox` with the new env hooks from the kernel, but this should also work with older LaTeXs. Note that this will not touch `\lstinputlisting`.